# Neither KeyListener nor Key Bindings will handle multiple key events

Tags: java

I'm trying to handle up to five concurrent keyPressed events.

I have tried listening for keyPressed and keyReleased events and adding/removing the keyCodes from an ArrayList respectively. This works for two keys, and sometimes three, however any more than that and no more keyPressed events are registered until the keyReleased events occur for presently pressed keys:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class KeyboardHandler implements KeyListener {
public static ArrayList<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    // System.out.println("Key pressed: " + e.getKeyCode());

    if (!keys.contains((Integer) e.getKeyCode())) {
        keys.add((Integer) e.getKeyCode());
        // System.out.println("Key added to keylist: " + e.getKeyCode());
    }


}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // System.out.println("Key released: " + e.getKeyCode());

    if (keys.contains((Integer) e.getKeyCode())) {
        keys.remove((Integer) e.getKeyCode());
        // System.out.println("Key removed from keylist: " + e.getKeyCode());
    }
}

public static void handleKeyInput() {
// I then go on to handle the items in the array list appropriately 
//using this method that is called by a thread.
```

I arrived at the conclusion that this can't be anything to do with using the arraylist, so ended up looking into key binding. As I understand now, key binds are a much better way of handling key events. However, my problem remains, no more than three keys are ever registered as being pressed until the presently pressed keys are released:

```
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;

public class KeyBinding extends JComponent{
    public KeyBinding(){

        InputMap im = this.getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap am = getActionMap();

        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false), "w_pressed");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, true), "w_released");

        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), "a_pressed");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true), "a_released");

        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, false), "s_pressed");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, true), "s_released");

        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), "d_pressed");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true), "d_released");

        am.put("w_pressed", new AbstractAction(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("W key is pressed");
            }


        });

        am.put("w_released", new AbstractAction(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("W key is released");
            }


        });

        am.put("a_pressed", new AbstractAction(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("A key is pressed");
            }


        });

        am.put("a_released", new AbstractAction(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("A key is released");
            }


        });

        am.put("s_pressed", new AbstractAction(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("S key is pressed");
            }


        });

        am.put("s_released", new AbstractAction(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("S key is released");
            }


        });

        am.put("d_pressed", new AbstractAction(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("D key is pressed");
            }


        });

        am.put("d_released", new AbstractAction(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(" key is released");
            }


        });
    }
}
```

I'm running Eclipse on a Mac, could it be some OS specific bug or am I doing something totally wrong? I've only been studying Java for a couple of weeks and this has me stumped. I hate asking non-specific questions and just posting blocks of code - it seems lazy of me, but I've tried and failed to solve this myself - all help is massively appreciated.

Comment: This is possibly a hardware limit (at the keyboard level), for [example](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/how-do-i-remove-the-limit-on-pc-keyboard-button-presses), [example](http://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx), [example](http://blog.controlspace.org/2010/08/n-key-rollover-what-it-is-and-how-to.html)

Comment: I didn't know keyboard ghosting was a thing! Could I be cheeky and ask you to compile on your machine to see if it definitely is a hardware thing? https://www.dropbox.com/s/bixxddp9g0lese1/Moving%20Circles.zip?dl=0

Comment: Ah, I just plugged a usb keyboard in and it all works fine now. Jesus christ,  wasted a lot of time on this today!
Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Don't forget, currently you only have two possible simultaneous key which could possible generate a result (the other two would cancel them out) :P